# Event handler arguments

Tags: c#, event-handling

I am using the following code to add buttons to a list:

```
for (int i=0; i < mov.Theat.Count(); i++)  
{  
    StackPanel st=new StackPanel();  
    st.Orientation=System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;  
    st.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;  
    TextBlock tx = new TextBlock();  
    tx.Text=mov.Theat[i];  
    st.Children.Add(tx);  
    TextBlock tx2=new TextBlock();  
    tx2.Text=mov.Time[i];  
    st.Children.Add(tx2);  
    Button test = new Button();  
    test.Width=450;  
    test.Content = st;  
    test.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Button_Click);  
    theatlist.Items.Add(test);  
}
```

As for the event handler, it is shown below:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{  
    Theat_Data TD=(App.Current as App).Theat.First(theat => theat.Name=="");  
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Theat"] = TD;  
    this.GoToPage(ApplicationPages.Theat);  
}
```

I want to pass some variable about the selected button in the even handler so how can this be done? And if this is not possible, then what options do I have to identify the button and pass some data about it to the event handler?

Comment: Thank you guys, all answers were helpful but HCL's answer was most detailed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your business object is called Thead_Data and you would like to have access to this object from within your Click-method:

During creation, attach your data object to the DataContext or the Tag property:

```
Button test = new Button(){DataContext=Theat[i]};
```

Within your event handler, cast the DataContext or the Tag-property to your business-object:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
 Button btn=(Button)sender;
 Theat_Data td=(Theat_Data)button.DataContext;

 ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the sender like this:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var clickedButton = sender as Button;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you are asking, but the "sender" param of the event handler *is* the button.  You should just be able to cast it:

```
   Button b = (Button)sender;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your [own event handler](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/04/15/events.html) and add your custom data in the event args.